# windowsphone 8.1 commandbar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, commandbar

Now I'm making Windows Phone 8.1 app with VS2015 and C# and XAML.
And Want to know about Commandbar.

I only use Secondary commandbar. So, I want to compress primary's space, When Commandbar pop up. but I can't solve this problem.

[Ideal Image, commandbar's height short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cxME.jpg)

now my code is here.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal" Background="Tomato">
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="appBarAboutButton" 
                          Label="about"
                          Click="appBarAboutButton_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands >
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is the expected behavior of Command bar and there is no work around for it. But there is a property called Content in Command bar. You can have a go at it to see if it fits your need.

> CommandBar has 3 properties you can use to add content and commands:
>   Content, PrimaryCommands, and SecondaryCommands. You can add any XAML
>   elements to the content area by setting the Content property.

Check this link for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.aspx

Comment: CodeNoob, thank you for your comment. I'll check that link.